# Creating multi level classes in PHP

Tags: php, class, object, inheritance, methods

I am working on a software project and have noticed when looking at other project's code, such as the Zend Framework, that they use some kind of inheriting multi-level classes.

An example is `$system->sessions->closeSession()`. I understand that objects provide similar functionality, but I was not aware that they could be used for actual callable methods.

How can I create a class with this technique?

Comment: That's not inheritance in itself, although those classes may well use inheritance (defined using the `extends` keyword). The object `$system` has a public attribute of `$sessions` which itself is an object, and that has a method of `closeSession`. In general, public attributes aren't the best approach: `$sessions` should have been a public `getSessions()` method, to keep it read-only.

Comment: Also, I find that having a getter method with appropriate phpdoc comments is more reliable in type-hinting terms than public attributes, although that could just be a Netbeans hiccup `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nothing special about it. in vague non-functional pseudo-code:

```
class Zend_Session {
    function closeSession() { ... }
}

class zend {
   public $sessions;
   function __construct() {
      $this->sessions = new Zend_Session;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now :) I did not realise it was that simple! My applications will work a bit smoother now.